# Passing a list to a function as a sequence of variables

Tags: functions, core-language

I have the set

```
l = {{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}};
```

and I am trying to get my function `f` to evaluate

```
f[x, {x1, x2}, {y1, y2}]
```

How do I manage this? I can achieve the last part by

```
f @@ {{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}}
```

but can't add `f[x]` back.

Comment: In addition to answers below you could add the additional definition to your function: `f[x_, {y : {_, _}, z : {_, _}}] := f[x, y, z]`

Answer (score 10):

```
l = {{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}};
f[x, ##] & @@ l
```

> f[x, {x1, x2}, {y1, y2}]

Answer (score 9):

```
l = {{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}};
f[x, Sequence @@ l]
```

also works.